# Spring boot + redis - request takes around same amount of time after restart

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I have implemented Redis in my spring boot app using the following `CacheConfig`

```
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(defaultTtl))
                .disableCachingNullValues();
    }
```

When I hit an endpoint for the first time, it takes about 2-3 seconds to send a response - the key gets saved on my Redis server. After that, the requests are sent back within 10-20 ms (while the app is still running). However, if I stop and restart the app, the initial request takes 2-3 seconds again. Key still exists on Redis.

I have used the `@Cacheable("someKey")` annotation on my service class. I put in some logs inside the method to see if it goes inside when sending the request but as expected, it doesn't as it has already been cached.

Shouldn't the response still be quick even if I restart the app?

Comment: It does appear like Spring Boot auto-configured a `simple` cache type i.e. in-memory caching... Is your `RedisCacheConfiguration` defined as Spring `@Bean`?

Comment: Yes it is defined as a Spring @Bean

Comment: Could you try to log the `CacheManager` bean type and check if it is indeed the `RedisCacheManager` that is auto-configured